# How to create a button for wind in Blender

Tags: animation, particles

For a 3D Winter Snow Simulation I'm working on in Blender for one of my college classes, I am required to create a button that causes wind to shift falling snow in a different direction. The following is what the instructor is looking for:

> The environment should have a Wind Wheel, such as pressing a button it starts or stops. Every time the wind wheel is turned on, the snow keeps falling and it is affect by the wind when it gets close to the wind wheel. For sake of simplicity, consider that the entire snow is affect once on the same high of the wind wheel, if the wind wheel is active.

Please tell me what I can do to accomplish this.

Comment: You have to do your own homework.

Comment: Homework sounds much more interesting than it was in my day.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/index.html) for the relation button ↔ snow, with and [force fields](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/force_fields/index.html#types) for the wind effect. Create your button object, and make it drive the properties of your wind.